# Play flash file(swf) in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

I have an asp.net webpage in which I want to play flash file(.swf). But webpage is presenting a blank white screen instead of playing that. The flash file is in same directory as of aspx page. Following is my code

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"
            width="180" height="640" id="menu" align="middle">

            <param name="movie" value="jan.swf"/>
            <param name="quality" value="high" />


            <embed src="jan.swf" quality="high" width="180" height="640" name="menu" align="middle"
                allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
        </object>
```

Please help

Comment: It seems to be pathing problem. Is path to "jan.swf" correct?

Comment: yes rahul jan.swf is correct :(

Comment: check this out http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_object.asp

Comment: may be the path problem but it is showing no error is there any way to check is that a path problem or not

Comment: @generalgmt this code is working fine in simple html page

Comment: Try it with an absolute path, than you will know if it is a path problem